# Automatically Change RMarkdown Text Styles from One to Another

Tags: r-markdown

Due to different journal requirements,  I need to frequently change certain text styles within Rmarkdown from one kind to another. For instance, here is an example Rmarkdown document.

````
---
title: "Changing format of Rmarkdown"
author: "Paul Hargarten"
date: "5/9/2019"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an $\mathcal{R}$ Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring **HTML**, **PDF**, and **MS Word* documents. For more details on using $\mathcal{R}$ Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>. $\matcal{R}$ is based on $\mathcal{S}$.

When you click the `Knit` button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. Calculate a `summary` as follows: 

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots
You can also embed plots, for example: `r  plot(pressure)`.
````

Without searching for the exact phrase, suppose that I would like to find and replace the following items:
 1. Change items in bold `** ... **` to italics `_ ... _`.
 2. Change items that look like `$\mathcal{ ... }$` to bold `** ... **`.
 3. Change special font `` `...` ``, except those that start with `r`, to `\code{ ... }`.
 4. Add dollar signs to `` `r ... ` ``  => `` $`r ... `$ ``.

Is this possible to use regex to make these formatting style changes in
    Rmarkdown? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is something that LaTeX is good at, but it will be harder with Markdown.

If you were entirely in LaTeX, you could define your own macros based on the uses for that markup.  For example,

```
\newcommand{\booktitle}[1]{\textbf #1}
```

used for book titles as `\booktitle{The Book}`.  If you wanted to switch book titles to italic, you'd just change that definition.

Doing this in R Markdown is possible, but you wouldn't be able to mark book titles using `**`.  You could do it (you can embed LaTeX in R Markdown), but it's ugly.  For example,

````
---
title: Using LaTeX
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

\newcommand{\booktitle}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

This is \booktitle{The Book}.
````

Once you're doing this, you might as well switch to Sweave-like `*.Rnw` format, or all the way to LaTeX.

Comment: Thank you; I understand that LaTeX or a Sweave-like `*.Rnw` file may be the way to go.  However, R Markdown has a `regex` option under the find bar in the code block. Could regular expression help me to search generally in R Markdown? If so, are the regular expressions in R Markdown the same as the ones used in R?

Comment: Though, it would be nice to find and replace in Markdown easily and without clunky code.

Comment: That controls the regex used in RStudio.  Those are similar to the ones used in R, but not the same.  This page https://www.r-bloggers.com/regular-expressions-in-r-vs-rstudio/ compares them; it's about 5 years old, so I don't know how accurate it is.  But putting together a regex to match bold face markers isn't trivial:  they don't need to be on one line, etc.